# How to disable CloudFlare "SmartErrors"?

Tags: cloudflare

I like CloudFlare but I don't like their custom 404 page overriding my MediaWiki 404 page.

This url `https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171226-How-can-I-turn-SmartErrors-on-or-off-on-my-site-` gives me

> oops
>
> You're not authorized to access this page

And somewhere else I found that it should be in my apps, but https://www.cloudflare.com/a/cloudflare-apps/couchwiki.org#r=cloudflare-apps?z=example.com&sso=1 is not showing my a SmartErrors app that I can turn off.

Is there still a way to turn off SmartErrors at all at this point?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. But you can use Page Rules to turn Smart Errors off. Just pick `example.com/*`. Choose Smart Errors:Off from the dropdown and turn the rule on.

I've been told that Smart Errors will be removed globally shortly. But in the meantime...